# Amazon S3 Upload via Post and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I've been trying in vain for 2 days now to do a simple upload to my Amazon S3 Bucket. Below is my rendered form:

```
    <form action="http://s3.amazonaws.com/MYBUCKETNAME" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="MYACCESSKEY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="UserUploads/TestUser/${filename}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://WWW.MYURL.COM/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="POLICY" />
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="SIGNATURE" />
    <div>
        Please specify a file, or a set of files:
        <input type="file" name="file" size="100" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

and my policy document looks like this:

```
    {
        expiration = "2011-12-08T12:00:00.000Z",
        conditions = [
                ["eq","bucket","MYBUCKETNAME"],
                ["eq","acl","private"],
                ["starts-with","$key","UserUploads/TestUser/"],
                ["eq","success_action_redirect", "HTTP://WWW.MYURL.COM/"]
            ]
    }
```

I get the following error:
Code: AccessDenied,
Message: Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "bucket", "MYBUCKETNAME"]

Does anyone have any ideas please, I'm grabbing at straws here. Also not sure if my Bucket Policy and ACL is correct.

Comment: I've also tried these parameters on the online Amazon Post Test tool -> http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html and I get the same results.

Comment: How are you generating the signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html#Access_Control

> Matching a Particular Value
>
> Description: There are certain fields that you want to match a
>   particular value, such as matching a bucket name or requiring that an
>   object is uploaded using the public-read access control policy. The
>   field value is case sensitive, but the name is not.
>
> Syntax: There are two ways to require that the field fieldname matches
>   the string value. The value is case sensitive. If the value starts
>   with a dollar sign ($), the dollar sign must be escaped with a
>   backslash (\$)

```
[ "eq", "$fieldname", "S" ],
```

(Note the $ prefix).

So your policy should have $ in sets where you using "eq" format

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this in C# with the S3 SDK (http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/), it's a bit more secure.

Here's my blog post with more detail: http://bradoyler.com/post/3614362044/uploading-an-image-with-aws-sdk-for-net-c.

Cheers and Good luck.

Comment: "Why not do this in C#....." Because his uploads go directly to S3 whereas yours go via your web server.

Comment: As Geoff said, it's to save on the bandwidth on my site.

Comment: nice, browser-based uploading looks pretty sweet. I'll try it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the following error:
Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: [\"eq\", \"$bucket\"

After many hours, I learned that you can't have a bucket with uppercase letters.  Changing the bucket to lowercase fixed it.

Comment: I had this same problem.  It appears you can use a bucket with uppercase letters if you use a standard html form post in a browser.  However, if you try to use AmazonS3Util.PostUpload it will fail with this error.  Thanks for leaving this answer it helped me tremendously.